# How to extract one icon from an icon grid .eps file (a pack of icons) using Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]I have been trying to figure this out for the last hour, but have not been able to yet. I am pretty sure this is a very basic operation.  Can anyone provide me the url to a basic tutorial or just the steps?  I just need to extract one icon from the grid of icons (pack of icons) that I just purchased and save it as a .png file so I can customize it with Adobe Photoshop.

Comment: If this is an eps file, it should be entirely editable? Make sure the layers are not locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Direct Selection Tool (the white arrow) to click-drag around one icon. Then `Edit > Copy`, `File > New`, `Edit > Paste`, `File > Save As...`.

Comment: Thank you so much(:  This was driving me absolutely batty!  It works quite well.